# PostgreSQL json_build_object nested

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

First things first: 
I'm using PostgreSQL 11.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit. :)

Im trying to create a JSON object directly from the database.

***My desired result is***

```
{
   "1": [],
   "2": [],
   "3": []
}
```

Imagine my tables like:

```
MyIdTable
_id_|__key__
  1     test1
  2     test2
  3     test3
```

```
MyKeyValueTable

__id__|__fkidmyidtable__|__value__
  1           1             test
  2           1             test1
  3           2             test2
  4           2             test3
```

Now I create a query

```
 select
        json_build_object(
            a.id,
            json_agg(
                b.*
            )
        )
          from "MyIdTable" a 
            inner join "MyKeyValueTable" b on a.id = b.fkidmyidtable group by a.id
```

This will get me as result, **multiple rows** with the desired result:

```
row 1: { 
         "1": [{ "id": 1, "fkidmyidtable": 1, "value": "test" }, { "id": 2, "fkidmyidtable": 1, "value": "test1" }]
       }
row 2: { 
         "2": [{ "id": 3, "fkidmyidtable": 2, "value": "test2" }, { "id": 4, "fkidmyidtable": 2, "value": "test3" }]
       }
```

After this I can use json_agg() to create almost my desired result. The issue is that it will create

```
[ { "json_build_object": {"1": [{ "id": 1, "fkidmyidtable": 1, "value": "test" }, { "id": 2, "fkidmyidtable": 1, "value": "test1" }]}, "json_build_object": { "2": [{ "id": 3, "fkidmyidtable": 2, "value": "test2" }, { "id": 4, "fkidmyidtable": 2, "value": "test3" }] }]
```

I would like to know if its possible to write a query to merge my created object into one json object like:

```
{
 "1": [{ "id": 1, "fkidmyidtable": 1, "value": "test" }, { "id": 2, "fkidmyidtable": 1, "value": "test1" }],
 "2": [{ "id": 3, "fkidmyidtable": 2, "value": "test2" }, { "id": 4, "fkidmyidtable": 2, "value": "test3" }]
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for taking the time to read :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you can add another level of aggregation and use `json_object_agg()`:

```
select json_object_agg(id, js) res
from (
    select a.id, json_agg(b.*) js
    from "MyIdTable" a 
    inner join "MyKeyValueTable" b on a.id = b.fkidmyidtable 
    group by a.id
) t
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!! : ) Will post as accepted answer in 4 minutes as I have to wait.